# How can i find which cisco switch port is connnected to specific port of Fortigate?

Tags: cisco, switching, fortigate, fortinet, lldp

there is any way to find that which switch port connected to mgmt port of fortigate?
for example can i enable lldp on Cisco switch and Fortigate together?
Fortigate 1500D (version 5.6.2) and switch is cisco-2960x-24TSL(ios ver 12.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the MAC address table on the switch to see on what port you learned the MAC address of the Fortigate's management interface.

It should be possible to enable LLDP on the Fortinet as of FortiOS 5.2 as well according to their [documentation](https://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/52data/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-whats-new-52/system.htm):

```
config system interface
  edit <name>
    set lldp-transmission enable
  end 
end
```

You can enable LLDP on your switch using the command `lldp run`. After that, you can use `show lldp neighbors` to see which LLDP speaking hosts are seen.

Comment: did i add any config in switch side?

Comment: Since you did not provide any configuration or details about the switch model or software version, I have no idea.

Comment: yes you right, I add Now more detail

Comment: I think LLDP is available on your switches (though 12.2 is pretty old). See my edit for additional info.

Comment: I now trying to enable LLDP on Fortgate and Cisco Switch, I think this is good idea

Answer (score 1):

**sh mac address-table** Find the Fortigate's MAC on that List

Comment: I need to return switch port name

Comment: Didnt understand "

I need to return switch port name", Just run the Command and find the Fortigate MAC in the list and it Shows the Interface name.

Comment: Command to find interface connected links #get system interfàce all"

Comment: Comand to find ARP table in fortigate firewall is "get system ARP"

Answer (score 0):

If it is layer3  switch and fortigate firewall and switch is connected on L3 interface means . Use "sh ip interfàce brief command

This command will display all interface status on switch  . You will have visibility of IP subnet of interface  connected to fortigate firewall

In case if firewall is connected with L2 switch then " show mac -address" table gives the visibility of total mac address devices connected of this switch . You will have firewall mac address connected to Switchport  in mac -address table .